# PHP read from end of file adding character

Tags: php, fopen, fseek

I need to read the last line of a potentially massive text file, without loading the entire file.  I think I have a pretty good solution worked out, but have a confusing bug.  For most entries, the function returns properly, but in one specific circumstance, it seems to double the last letter of the file.  Here is the test script I worked out (the contents of news.txt is the single word "NEWS"):

```
<?php
echo "file contains: ".file_get_contents('news.txt')."<br/>";
$lastLine = getLastLine("news.txt");
echo "function returns: ".$lastLine;

function getLastLine($filename){
    $f      = fopen($filename, 'r');
    $cursor = -1;
    $line   = '';
    fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
    $char   = fgetc($f);
    echo "initial read: <br/>";  // DEBUG
    echo $cursor." | ".$char." | ".$line."<br/>";  // DEBUG
    // test for empty file
    if($char === false)
        return false;
    // Trim trailing newline chars of the file
    while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r" || $char === " ") {
        fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
        $char = fgetc($f);
    }
    echo "kill new lines: <br/>"; // DEBUG
    echo $cursor." | ".$char." | ".$line."<br/>";  // DEBUG
    // Read until the start of file or first newline char
    echo "running loop: <br/>";  // DEBUG
    while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r" ) {
        // Prepend the new char
        $line = $char . $line;
        echo $cursor." | ".$char." | ".$line."<br/>"; // DEBUG
        fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
        $char = fgetc($f);
    }
    return trim($line);
}
?>
```

The output looks like this:

```
file contains: NEWS
initial read: 
-1 | S | 
kill new lines: 
-1 | S | 
running loop: 
-1 | S | S
-2 | S | SS
-3 | W | WSS
-4 | E | EWSS
-5 | N | NEWSS
function returns: NEWSS
```

It appears that index -1 and -2 are identical, however, the file_get_contents confirms that the file's contents are just "NEWS".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you never reset $cursor? You always do a $cursor-- but never set to the original value. Or am I missing something? :)

Comment: you'd be better off slurping in a full string (e.g. 1024 chars), reversing it, hunting for the first new line char, etc.. than doing a char-by-char reading. that will be VERY slow, especially if the file has very long lines of text.

Comment: I'm not removing anything, just moving the cursor back, one char at a time from the end of the file the `fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END)` decrements the cursor after each run... but that gives me an idea... I may need to run `--$cursor`, instead of `$cursor--`

Comment: @MarcB the file's lines are less than 20 characters long, but the file may be several megabytes.  It's a potentially huge log file.

Comment: If you just need the last line, try this: `tail -n 1 $file1`; with backticks around it (it won't show in a comment)

Comment: @DJHell your question lead me to the answer.  I was decrementing the cursor with `$cursor--`, and reading it in the same operation.  so, I was reading the original value, then incrementing.  I, instead, needed to run `--$cursor`, so the decrement happened before reading.  Thanks

Comment: @aynber I actually tried tail first, but this particular file is piped from a program (pianobar) that outputs weird escape characters that break tail.  no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

so, my issue was one of those "duh" issues in comp sci.  I was using `$curser--` to decrement my curser, while reading it in the same line.  as a result, I was reading the curser, then decrementing... I changed it to `--$curser`, and now everything is good.